# How to add item to array with useState hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I am new to React and I searched examples for this questions but I could not achieve to do this.

I make 2 separate calls to backend and getting 2 different dto and I want to put them into one table data instead of 2 separate ones.

Here is my code:

```
const [lensTableData, setLensTableData] = useState<InternalDTO>();
    const [dbsaTableData, setDbsaTableData] = useState<InternalDTO>();
    
useEffect(() => {
        context.services.adapterStatus.getLensAdapterStatus()
            .then((resp) => setLensTableData(resp));

        context.services.adapterStatus.getDbsaAdapterStatus()
            .then((resp) => setDbsaTableData(resp));
    }, [])
```

It is working but what I want to do is to make just 1 array instead of 2 different and I want to add 2nd one into array after the first one. How can I combine them ?

Comment: i somehow cannot answere this question, but try this:
 setDbsaTableData( [...dbsaTableData, ...resp] )